# How can I compare and filter out the files which are modified in last 20 mins using powershell?

Tags: powershell, getdate, get-childitem

I need to filter only the files which are modified in last 20 mins. Below is the code I have written.

```
$Today = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
$filecreation = Get-ChildItem "D:\logs\" -Recurse
Foreach($file in $filecreation)
{
    if ($file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") -gt $Today)
    {
        Write-Host $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
    }
}
```

Output is below:

```
08/26/2020 07:39 PM
08/26/2020 07:54 PM
08/26/2020 10:58 AM
08/26/2020 07:54 PM
08/26/2020 12:01 AM
08/26/2020 12:01 AM
08/26/2020 12:01 AM
```

Problem:
***So you see, I have got the files written in morning as well. I want to compare the AM and PM as well. Can somebody please help me with this.***

Also, the I have multiple date folders inside "D:\logs". And the same are also captured in the output. I just want to compare the file and copy. How can I ignore the folders in Get-ChildItem?

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: Don't convert to string when doing the comparison. Only convert to string on output to the console.

Answer (score 1):

## Stop turning `[datetime]` objects into strings for comparison!

The `[datetime]` type already supports three-way comparisons, so comparing *string representations* of existing `[datetime]` values is completely unnecessary - and unless you're using a strictly endian date format (like `yyyyMMddHHmmss`) it also *won't work as intended* - simply because the rules for sorting something *alphabetically* are different than sorting according to some description of time.

```
# $Today is now a [datetime] value, not a string
$Today = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20)
$filecreation = Get-ChildItem "D:\logs\" -Recurse
Foreach($file in $filecreation)
{
    # Now we just compare them directly as-is
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -gt $Today)
    {
        Write-Host $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use !D Attribute to search files and not directories**
You can use the following code. This eliminates the sub-directories(by using *!Directory or !D*) search and use 24 hr format to get the final files with added AM and PM.

```
$Today = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt")
$filecreation = Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory -Path "D:\logs\" 
Foreach($file in $filecreation)
{
    if ($file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt") -gt $Today)
    {
        Write-Host $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt")
    }
}
```

*Recurse* is not necessary until and unless if the subdirectory files needs to be compared

Comment: As for this ...[Use !D Attribute to search files and not directories] .. Get-ChildItem has a -File parameter for exactly this reason.

Comment: yes, file can also be used with no recurse  or can pass multiple attributes/parms from -Attributes